# CodeIgniter 4 request.getVar function not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

In my codignitor project I have the following view

```
public function index(){
       $whatever = $this->request->getVar("value");
}
```

I have similar code all over my project, which was 100% working until today, when suddenly it stopped

now `$whatever` is `NULL`

However if I just change the code to use:

```
 $whatever = $this->request->getGet();
 $result = $whatever['value'];
```

result will be equal to the value....

Here value is a GET parameter in the url like: `example.com?value=1`

According to the docs:

> "The getVar() method will pull from $_REQUEST, so will return any data
> from $_GET, $POST, or $_COOKIE."

when I checked the value of $_GET I see my parameter as expected.

Is this a bug in codeignitor? (the strange thing is it only suddenly stopped working)

Comment: It seems a better approach to use getGet instead of getVar if you're parameter is always in $_GET

Answer (score 1):

I ended up submitting an issue on github here: https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/4418

which was reportedly solved here:
https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/pull/4493

> Description In the current version, when the request is the get method
> and the content-type is json, the $_REQUEST parameter cannot be
> obtained

apparently it was an issue with that specific version (v4.0.4) that is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `$this->request->getVar()` was not working inside models. As per the documentation of CodeIgniter 4:
"If you are not within a controller, but still need access to the application’s Request object, you can get a copy of it through the Services class"

So you would access REQUEST variables like:

```
$request = \Config\Services::request();
$some_field = $request->getVar('field_name'); // or getPost for $_POST array
```

Hope it would help others